# How to get transition name from current issue programmatically?

Tags: action, jira, transition

i want to get transition name when changing one status to another using api.

for example,i want to get "Resolve" action name when resolve an open issue,and change the status to "Resolved"

my jira version is jira 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use getAvailableActions if you are using API.

**RemoteNamedObject[] getAvailableActions(java.lang.String token,
                                        java.lang.String issueKey)
                                        throws RemoteException**
Returns the available actions that can be applied to an issue.

**Parameters:**
token - the SOAP authentication token.
issueKey - the issue to get actions for.

**Returns:**
the available actions that can be applied to an issue

**Throws:**
RemoteException - if something dramatic happens during this operation

[Jira Soap API documentation](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/4.4/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#getAvailableActions%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: hi,i don't want to get some actions those are available to an issue,but want to get current being executed action name.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this depending the context you are, like this post suggest
http://jira.10933.n7.nabble.com/How-to-get-transition-name-from-current-issue-td18047.html

Behind Behaviours plugin you can retrieve the transition ID with getFieldById("action").getFormValue()

Regards